# How to get profile detail Using OneDrive API Android

Tags: android, profile, onedrive, live-sdk

I am using OneDrive  `compile('com.onedrive.sdk:onedrive-sdk-android:1.0.2')` version

and trying to get **Profile pic and email** detail from `IOneDriveClient` but not found a way to get this.

1. Profile Pic
2. Email

Please help to get these detail.

Answer (score 0):

You can find the documentation here about [Getting user data (Android) using Microsoft Live SDK](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn659734.aspx) for OneDrive.

> The Live SDK for Android enables your Android app to access a user's
>   info on Microsoft OneDrive.

[Microsoft Live SDK Home Page (Android Apps)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn631814.aspx)

[Documentation for the Classes available in the API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/hh846808.aspx)

Sample code from the page for finding owner name:

```
this.greetUserButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        client.getAsync("USER ID", new LiveOperationListener() {
            public void onComplete(LiveOperation operation) {
                try {
                    JSONObject result = operation.getResult();
                    String name = result.getString("first_name");
                    // Display user's first name.
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    // Display error if first name is unavailable.
                    return;
                }
            }
            public void onError(LiveOperationException exception, LiveOperation operation) {
                // Display error if operation is unsuccessful.
            }
        });
    }
});
```

I think if you start digging further from here and exploring the used classes, you'll figure out how to extract the rest of the information you want.

Comment: I am not getting client.getAsync, in using IOneDriveClient, I think above method is from old API.

Comment: Have you declared `client` as an instance of `LiveConnectClient`? See step three on the page.

Comment: LiveSDK Last modified: March 10, 2015, After this they release new API, I am using that, please check GitHub, I am looking answer using new API
Thanks for your response @Virus

Comment: @IshRoid did you find a way to get profile pic and email? Or at least email and user first and last name?

Comment: @DoubleK No :-(  it is possible only if you are using API request, not SDK model class,, i solved it my self by using API instead of using there SDK. worst SDK i ever found :-(

Comment: @IshRoid yes, it's a bit annoying, I started upgrading my app that uses LiveSDK since it says that everyone should move to OneDriveAPI, but the I found that I can't get profile photo and that I should use msGraphAPI, when I implemented that part it throws an error that only beta version supports profile photo. So now I will have to move to REST API :(.